# Add javascript to cover page button

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I have a button on my [cover page](http://www.benjamin-schumann.com) and I need to assign to it 1 line of javascript code (namely `javascript:languageClicked(0);` to work with this neat addon: [Multilingualizer](http://www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/shop/multilingualizer/)) .

So the button should execute that line of code and do its usual job, namely to send the user to my main webpage.

thx in advance

Comment: I am sorry, but please re-state your question. Absolutely no idea what you mean. When you say assign, do you mean using a `<a href=javascript:languageClicked(0);>BUTTONCODEHERE</a>` type of assignment, or do you mean code like a variable, etc...

Comment: Hi,sorry, I am not a javascript expert so I might not use common language here at all. What I want is simple: have that button do its usual job of directing users to a specific webpage AND execute this line of javascript code. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but which button exactly? I see a lot.

Comment: thx Nick, the big beast saying "Enter". I dont mean the social media buttons...

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: languageClicked is not defined` when running that line in the console. Are you sure you have the appropriate Javascript dependencies loaded within your site?

Comment: hm, you might be right that the language stuff is not initialized at that point... I will try to inject it to that cover page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77034/discussion-between-nick-newman-and-benjamin).

Answer (score 2):

Is the languageClicked function code from Multilingualizer? If so, maybe that addon isn't enabled correctly on your page or something and the js files for it are not being loaded.

But, once they are loaded. You can replace your button with this code:

```
<a href="javascript:languageClicked(0);window.location='/expnew';" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1430851625668_627">ENTER</a>
```

[Screenshot](http://i.gyazo.com/45fa96e5474c84fd6a033968076316db.png)

Since you want the user to be redirected to `/expnew` after activating `languageClicked`.

Hope this helps! Also, there is one catch though; don't change this unless you know for sure you have those JS libraries loaded. ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. One last awefully stupid last question: How can I add that code of yours using the squarespace environment?

Comment: I can take a look at it through chat if you want. There should be some type of panel where you can edit HTML inside the squarespace interface, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Without some HTML snippets and the name of the button you are working with, it is hard to know exactly how to help. However, I can share some general knowledge that may provide the answer for you.

The two most common ways that JavaScript triggers are implemented are:

**1. `<a>` "link buttons":**

Your code might look something like:

```
<a href="javascript:languageClicked(0)">Click me!</a>
```

**2. `<input>`/`<button>`/any element `onclick` events:**

Your code might look something like:

```
<button onclick="javascript:languageClicked(0)">Click me!</button>
```